# TRIGGER não funciona no MYSQL

Tags: mysql, trigger

Estou tentando fazer uma TRIGGER que insira dados numa tabela, assim que sejam inseridos dados em outra tabela.

Tabela Original:

```
    CREATE TABLE tbGuia ( 
  codigo_guia INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  descricao_guia VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  data_vencimento_guia DATE NOT NULL,
  ambito_guia VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  status_guia VARCHAR(45) DEFAULT "Pendente",
  codigo_cliente INT NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_tbGuia PRIMARY KEY (codigo_guia),
  CONSTRAINT fk_tbGuia_client
    FOREIGN KEY (codigo_cliente)
    REFERENCES tbCliente (codigo_cliente)     
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Tabela que desejo povoar com a TRIGGER:

```
CREATE TABLE tbClienteGuia (
  codigo_cliente INT NOT NULL,
  codigo_guia INT NOT NULL,
  data_visualizacao DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT "0000-00-00",
  data_postagem DATE NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_TbClienteGuia PRIMARY KEY (codigo_cliente, codigo_guia, data_visualizacao, data_postagem),
  CONSTRAINT fk_tbClienteGuia 
    FOREIGN KEY (codigo_cliente)
    REFERENCES tbCliente (codigo_cliente)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT fk_tbGuiaCliente
    FOREIGN KEY (codigo_guia)
    REFERENCES tbGuia (codigo_guia)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

A Trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER vincular_guia_cliente AFTER INSERT ON tbguia
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tbclienteguia (codigo_cliente, codigo_guia, data_visualizacao, data_postagem)
    VALUES (NEW.codigo_cliente, NEW.codigo_guia, "0000-00-00", CURDATE());
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Alguma sugestão?
OBS: não dá erro, apenas não aciona a trigger quando faço a inserção na tbGuia.

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa garantir que ao executar a trigger, os dados de referencia estejam disponíveis.

tanto para:

```
REFERENCES tbCliente (codigo_cliente)
```

> Onde o codigo_cliente precisa ser garantido estar cadastrado.

Quanto para:

```
REFERENCES tbGuia (codigo_guia)
```

> Onde o codigo_guia precisa garantir estar cadastrado.

Se estas duas contrainsts não forem garantidas ssua trigger vai falhar na execução.

Comment: Mas se a trigger aciona AFTER INSERT (apenas após eu inserir os dados na tbguia), consequentemente, se o INSERT funcionar, as constraints estarão garantidas.

Comment: Sim, normal que seja acionado, pois a inserção em tbGuia ocorreu de forma OK, mas o que está entre BEGIN e END, pode falhar por causa desses motivos que citei e outros mais.